# SQL create statement incorrect syntax near auto increment

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, auto-increment, sql-server-identity

I created the following table, but I got the error below;

> *Incorrect syntax near 'AUTO_INCREMENT'.*

SQL:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[MY_TABLE] (
    [ID] INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    [NAME]          NVARCHAR (100) NULL,
    [SCHOOL]             NVARCHAR (100) NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (ID)
);
```

I think I have done everything right. Can someone help me out?

Answer (score 48, accepted):

It is [`IDENTITY`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186775.aspx) not `AUTO_INCREMENT` in SQL Server.

Try this instead:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[MY_TABLE] (
    [ID] INT NOT NULL IDENTITY(1, 1),
    [NAME]          NVARCHAR (100) NULL,
    [SCHOOL]             NVARCHAR (100) NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (ID)
);
```

Comment: Yes that worked. According to W3c http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_autoincrement.asp it was auto_increment

Comment: May i know what (1,1) means ?

Comment: @sharonHwk - The first one is the start number, the second is the seeding, so `(1, 1)` means: 1, 2, 3, 4, ...

Comment: @sharonHwk - On the link you provided you need to keep reading down to the part where it says "Syntax for SQL Server"

Answer (score 2):

Its not [AUTO_INCREMENT](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd338603.aspx). Here the [Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/1fa93/1) from sqlfiddle

Answer (score 2):

Use [**IDENTITY**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-table-transact-sql-identity-property?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=sql-server-ver16#syntax) for **MSSQL** as shown below. ***AUTO_INCREMENT** is for **MySQL** and **MariaDB**:

```sql
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[MY_TABLE] (
    [ID] INT NOT NULL IDENTITY, -- Here
    ...
);
```

In addition, you can have **a custom IDENTITY** with **"()"** as shown below. The 1st argument is for **start value** and the 2nd argument is for **increment value** so in the example below, if first inserting a row, **ID** is `20` and if second inserting a row, **ID** is `23`, then **ID** is `26`, `29`, `32`...:

```sql
                               -- Increment value
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[MY_TABLE] (--  ↓
    [ID] INT NOT NULL IDENTITY(20, 3),
    ...                     --  ↑
);                          -- Start value
```

And, `IDENTITY` is equivalent to `IDENTITY(1, 1)`.