# I get the error incorrect syntax near ... in Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I am trying to write this SQL code in Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio:

```sql
create table Countries
(
    Id INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
    Name VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL
);
```

and the problem is that I get this error on the comma:

```
Incorrect syntax near ','. Expecting ID, QUOTED_ID, STRING or TEXT_LEX.
```

and error in the 50:

```
Incorrect syntax near '50'. Expecting '(', or Select.
```

Just saying that I am beginner and I am not sure what is the error.

Comment: Please refer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15049434/sql-create-statement-incorrect-syntax-near-auto-increment

Comment: "I am beginner" is not an excuse to avoid looking up and learning basic syntax.

Comment: This is the official SQL Server [CREATE TABLE documentation reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-table-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15). Although syntax is similar to other ISO SQL database products, each has extensions not covered by the standard. Always consult the vendor documentation as the authoritative source.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using MySQL the following is the syntax:

```
create table Countries
(
    Id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    Name VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (Id)
);
```

If you are using MSSQL the following is the syntax:

```
create table Countries
(
    Id INT NOT NULL IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY,
    Name VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL
);
```

Comment: Thanks that helped I was not sure because I was working with MySQL and I have to use MSSQL now

Answer (score 0):

The `AUTO_INCREMENT` keyword is used in MySQL.
SQL Server uses `IDENTITY` to perform the [auto-increment feature](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_autoincrement.asp).

So your T-SQL code should be:

```
CREATE TABLE Countries (
    Id int NOT NULL IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY,
    Name varchar(50) NOT NULL
);
```